# can anyone help me to save canvas image to sql ? database =registration ...table: users....column:username , image[longblob]

Tags: javascript, mysql

directly to say I don't know JS clearly(so I don't understand any logic to store image in sql) ... I am just a learner[1st year CE student)... I learned backend though(sql,php) and I have to submit this project but I am stock.... I am completely unknown to store image directly to sql as I click 'continue' button.... all my friends are new to it and I don't have enough time to learn JS... There were many solution avilable but I don't understand any of them... please help me to maintain my code.... thanks

```html
<?php include('server.php'); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>HIMALAYA COLLEGE EXIBITION</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Tangerine">
 </head>
 <body>
 <br>
 <br>
 <br>
 <div class="capture">
 <video id="video" width="400" height="300" title="capture your photo" autoplay></video>
 <button id="snap" name="snap">Snap Photo</button>
 <br>
 <canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="300"></canvas>
 <br><br>
 <a href="#" id="afterimage">Continue</a>
 
</div>
<script>
// Grab elements, create settings, etc.
var video = document.getElementById('video');

// Get access to the camera!
if(navigator.mediaDevices && navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
    // Not adding `{ audio: true }` since we only want video now
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true }).then(function(stream) {
        video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
        video.play();
    });
}
//setup
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var video = document.getElementById('video');

// Trigger photo take
document.getElementById("snap").addEventListener("click", function() {
 context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, 400, 300);

});
</script>

<br>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You gotta use [toBlob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toBlob): `canvas.toBlob((blob) => { ... });` Pretty sure this has been asked already on SO. I’m writing a full response anyway. Just wait…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So your script is already capable of taking snapshots from the video. Now you have to convert the canvas data to a blob and send it to your server through ajax. This is not especially difficult with modern browsers.

```js
document.getElementById('snap').addEventListener('click', function() {
  context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, 400, 300);
  canvas.toBlob(function (blob) {
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open('POST', 'uploadimage.php');

    req.onload = function () {
      console.log('upload complete, server response:', req.response);
    };

    console.log('uploading snapshot...');
    req.send(blob);
  });
});
```

Open your console (F12) to see log messages. In production you’ll have to produce HTML feedback for the user.

The server part is a bit more complicated. First, create a PHP script named `uploadimage.php`. This script will retrieve uploaded file using the `php://input` stream.

As usual when dealing with user-submitted data, you need to perform some security checks. You want to verify that the uploaded file is an image type (see [mime_content_type](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php)).

You also need to authenticate the user to not allow everyone (or any bot) to upload things to your server. I won’t tell you how to do it, it’s out of the scope of this topic.

Last thing, we need to choose a file name that won’t collide with an existing one. A good candidate is a string based on the current time (see [microtime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)). You may also want to add a prefix related to the authenticated user.

(**Edit:** well, sorry, I forgot you wanted it stored in a database. Tell me if you manage to adapt this script. If not, I’ll write a more appropriate response.)

```php
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');

define('PREFIX', 'banana-');

$fd = fopen('php://input', 'rb');
$mimeType = mime_content_type($fd);
fclose($fd);
$matchResult = preg_match('#^image/(\w+)#', $mimeType, $matches);

if ($matchResult === false) {
    header('HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error');
    echo "Couldn't parse MIME type";
}
else if ($matchResult === 0) {
    header('HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request');
    echo "Wrong MIME type";
}
else {
    $fileExt = $matches[1];
    $fileName = PREFIX . number_format(microtime(true), 6, '-', '') . '.' . $fileExt;

    $putResult = file_put_contents($fileName, file_get_contents('php://input'));
    if ($putResult === false) {
        header('HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error');
        echo "Couldn't write file";
    }
    else {
        echo 'Ok';
    }
}
```

---

**Edit 2:** Updating as I progress. The problem is more complex than I thought. It appears that we can’t use `php://input` when we want to mix the blob with other POST data – these will be required for authentication.

For now I have a functional backend script to receive and store the image, but *without* authentication.

```php
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');
ini_set('html_errors', '0');

function sendError($message, $code = 500) {
    header("HTTP/1.0 $code");
    die($message);
}

$fd = fopen('php://input', 'rb');
$mimeType = mime_content_type($fd);
fclose($fd);

$matchResult = preg_match('#^image/#', $mimeType);

if ($matchResult === false) {
    sendError("Couldn't parse MIME type");
}
if ($matchResult === 0) {
    sendError('Wrong MIME type', 400);
}

$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost:3306', 'root', '', 'registration');
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    sendError($mysqli->connect_error);
}
$mysqli->set_charset('utf8mb4') or sendError($mysqli->error);

$username = 'Homer';
$contents = file_get_contents('php://input');

$query = 'INSERT INTO uploads (username, file) VALUES (?, ?)';
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query)              or sendError($mysqli->error);
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $username, $contents) or sendError($stmt->error);
$stmt->execute()                              or sendError($stmt->error);

echo 'Ok';
```

---

**Edit 3:** Here we are. To upload mixed content via ajax, a [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects) is of greater help. To receive it on the server side, do the classic way with `$_FILES`.

I eventually figured out that, in order to authenticate the user, the best way is to use the session. In fact you don’t even need additional request parameters, but let’s stick with the FormData solution, as you may want to send metadata and some security measures, e.g. a [CSRF token](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#Synchronizer_.28CSRF.29_Tokens).

Here’s the updated client script:

```
document.getElementById('snap').addEventListener('click', function() {
  context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, 400, 300);
  canvas.toBlob(function (blob) {
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('snapshot', blob);
    formData.append('image-description', 'MFW Im writing an answer on SO');

    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open('POST', 'uploadimage.php');

    req.onload = function () {
      console.log('upload complete, server response:', req.response);
    };

    console.log('uploading snapshot...');
    req.send(formData);
  });
});
```

And the updated server script:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');
ini_set('html_errors', '0');

function sendError($message, $code = 500) {
    header("HTTP/1.0 $code");
    die($message);
}

session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) sendError('Please log in', 401);

if (!isset($_FILES['snapshot'])) sendError('Missing file', 400);

$fd = fopen($_FILES['snapshot']['tmp_name'], 'rb');
$mimeType = mime_content_type($fd);
fclose($fd);

$matchResult = preg_match('#^image/#', $mimeType);

if ($matchResult === false) {
    sendError("Couldn't parse MIME type");
}
if ($matchResult === 0) {
    sendError('Wrong MIME type', 400);
}

$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost:3306', 'root', '', 'registration');
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    sendError($mysqli->connect_error);
}
$mysqli->set_charset('utf8mb4') or sendError($mysqli->error);

$username = $_SESSION['username'];
$contents = file_get_contents($_FILES['snapshot']['tmp_name']);

$query = 'INSERT INTO uploads (username, file) VALUES (?, ?)';
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query)              or sendError($mysqli->error);
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $username, $contents) or sendError($stmt->error);
$stmt->execute()                              or sendError($stmt->error);

echo 'Ok';
```

A note about HTTP codes: I tried to respond with somehow meaningful codes like REST API endpoints do. But I think HTTP codes are a matter of personal opinion, and I don’t claim I chose the more appropriate ones. Feel free to change them, or not to use them at all.

Comment: sorry to say but I didn;t get the second part :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/2221034/watilin how to save in database??? I got confused in second part

Comment: Yup, sorry, I went on my tracks and forgot you wanted it stored in a database. Can you show me how you handle database logic? What API you use, what are your table and column names, etc.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/2221034/watilin do you need more information ? :)

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/users/2221034/watilin
in mysql......database name-registration ..... table-name:users....column:username,batch,password_1,password_2,image(blob)....
I am using apache as server(XAMPP) and all pages(registration.php,login.php) are connected to server.php shown bellow

```html
<?php
 session_start();

 $username = "";
 $errors = array();
 /*if( ! empty( $_POST )) {
  print_r($_POST);}*/
 //connect to the database
 $db = mysqli_connect('localhost:3306', 'root', '', 'registration');
 /*if($db->connect_error){
  echo'sorry';
 }*/
 //if register button is clicked
 //link with the register
 if(isset($_POST['register'])){
   $username = $_POST['username'];
   $batch = $_POST['batch'];
   $password_1 = $_POST['password_1'];
   $password_2 = $_POST['password_2'];
   //ensure that the form are filled properly
   if(empty($username)){
    array_push($errors,"Username is required!!!");
   }
   if(empty($batch)){
    array_push($errors,"Batch is required!!!");
   }
   if(empty($password_1)){
    array_push($errors,"Password is required!!!");
   }
   if($password_1 != $password_2)
   {
    array_push($errors,"password do not match!!!");
   }
   //if no error save user to database
   if (count($errors)==0)
   {
    $password = md5($password_1);//encrypt password before storing in database(security)
    //$sql = "INSERT INTO users (username,batch,password) VALUES ('$username', '$batch', '$password')";
    mysqli_query($db,"INSERT INTO users (username, batch, password_1, password_2) VALUES ('$username', '$batch', '$password','$password')");
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    $_SESSION['success'] = "you are now registered ^_^";
    header('location: index.php'); //redirect to home page

   }
 }
 //log user in from login page
 if (isset($_POST['login'])) {
  $username = $_POST['username'];
  $password = $_POST['password_1'];

  //ensure that the forms are filled properly
  if(empty($username)) {
   array_push($errors, "Username is required");
  }
  if(empty($password))
  {
   array_push($errors, "Password is required");
  }
  if(count($errors) == 0) {
    $password = md5($password);//encrypting password
    $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password_1='$password'";
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
   if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1) {
    //log user in
     $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    $_SESSION['success'] = "you are now logged in ^_^";
    header('location: index2.php');//redirecting to home page
 
   }
   else{
     array_push($errors,"wrong username or password");
   }
  }
 }




?>
```

Comment: You have SQL injection vulnerabilities, for example when username is `' OR TRUE;--`. Use [real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) or [prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/2221034/watilin ......yes in my table -'users] ..... I already have column -'image[blob]' ... at first data is registered and then login page appear.... after login it goes to sanp phtoto page .... and from there I am unable to store image in database.....  the snap photo was loaded based on the username,,,, i.e ,... if I am able to store image in database,,,, it will be stored in the column -image.. in which the username is logged in.... since two pase are related to each other :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/2221034/watilin since it is just the minor project .....I am not going to host it anyhow....so sql injection can be considered for a while :)

Comment: Doesn’t cost that much though, and a good habit to take. https://www.xkcd.com/327/ Anyway, did you see I edited my answer?